# Pentium 4 mobile - auto downclocking?

Tags: cpu, performance

When I'm using my laptop temperature of my processor often exceeds 60C. Is it possible that my processor can automatically slowdown in case of preventing overheating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The P4 mobile does indeed feature this functionality, if I recall correctly, it's now (on most models) bundled with the traditional [EIST/SpeedStep](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/SpeedStep) functionality. There *may* be an option to disable it in your BIOS, on desktop computers it would almost definitely be there, but on a laptop it is less likely as usually the laptop manufacturer themselves requests the removal or locking of certain features that the BIOS supports.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the P4 mobile has this feature and you might find the machine's BIOS settings has some configuration settings for this too.